# Крашится приложение при вызове активити с картами

Tags: activity, android, google-maps-api-2

В приложении использую google maps api v2. Стектрейс ошибки:

```
    09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.post_req/com.example.post_req.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2851)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2234)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at com.example.post_req.MapActivity.initilizeMap(MapActivity.java:84)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at com.example.post_req.MapActivity.onResume(MapActivity.java:98)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1236)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4613)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2796)
09-13 14:45:57.277: E/AndroidRuntime(21069):    ... 12 more
```

сам код активити

```
public class MapActivity extends SuperActivity {
private GoogleMap googleMap;
public String s;
public String [] str;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.map);

 }

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */

private void addMarker()
{
    int cl = getIntent().getIntExtra("class", 0);
    if (cl == 1)
    {
        double [] x = getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("xArr");
        double [] y = getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("yArr");
        String [] title = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("title");
        try {
            initilizeMap();
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            {
                LatLng POINT = new LatLng(x[i], y[i]);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(POINT)
                .title(title[i]));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (cl == 2)
    {
        double x = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("x", 0);
        double y = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("y", 0);
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        try {
            initilizeMap();
            LatLng POINT = new LatLng(x, y);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                      .position(POINT)
                                      .title(title));               
            movCam(POINT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void movCam(LatLng POINT)
{
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(POINT, 15));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), null);

 // Construct a CameraPosition focusing on Mountain View and animate the camera to that position.
 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
     .target(POINT)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
     .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
     .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
     .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
     .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
    addMarker();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"> 
    <fragment       
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraTargetLat="43.0366700"
        map:cameraTargetLng="44.6677800"
        map:cameraZoom="12"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:uiCompass="false"
        map:uiRotateGestures="true"
        map:uiScrollGestures="true"
        map:uiTiltGestures="false"
        map:uiZoomControls="true"
        map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Проблема решилась переименованием

android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

в

android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

и исправил назначение переменной карты

```
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();
```

Comment: поставьте на 84 строку breakpoint, и посмотрите через вью Expressions, какой выражение у вас получается равным null

Comment: В манифесте  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="тут_число"/> какое?

Comment: 10 версия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ведь написано же, что ошибка в методе initilizeMap() в 84 строке

> com.example.post_req.MapActivity.initilizeMap(MapActivity.java:84)

Comment: Я никакой ошибки там не вижу. Если эта функция вызывается в OnCreate, то приложение нормально запускается, а именно в OnResume что-то не получается

Comment: можете написать что содержится в 84 строке?

Comment: googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: А покажите map.xml.

Comment: добавил в первый пост

Comment: Мне кажеться ваш ответ более походит на комментарий.

Comment: Проблему решил.